# Factorising to find eigenvalues of a matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, factoring

I am currently doing a subject called 'Linear Algebra for data analysis'. I am simply having trouble with a fundamental factorising element when finding my eigenvalues from a matrix. If for example I have found the following.....

-1 as a factor of x^3+x^2+2x-4 , how do I find the remaining eigenvalues?

Comment: Did you try synthetic division

Comment: Horner's algorithm.

Comment: By the way: $\;-1\;$ is **not** a root of that cubic...but $\;1\;$ is .

Answer (score 2):

Complete the cubic knowing $\;x-1\;$ divides it:

$$x^3+x^2+2x-4=(x-1)(x^2+2x+4)$$

Now use the usual formula for the roots of a quadratic. You shall get a conjugate pair of complex non-real roots.